# VBA Override Error 6 Overflow (Create Infinite Loop)?

Tags: vba, overflow

I want an infinite loop in VBA (I have done this in Java and C++ before). I keep getting "Overflow" with the VBCritical red circle X.

Here is my code. The Error <>0 is supposed to recognize the overflow and ignore it to let the macro continue looping infinitely, but I still get the overflow VBCritical MsgBox.

I want to print the numbers out in column A. This part works right now: it prints "2".

Here is my code:

```
Sub InfiniteLoop()
Dim counter As Integer
counter = 1
Do While counter > 0
    counter = counter + 1

Loop
If Error <> 0 Then
    Do While counter > 0
    counter = counter + 1
    Cells(counter, "A").Value = counter
    Loop
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You would need to reset `counter` to 1 ... this is not a good way of doing whatever it is your trying to do, if you explain more there will be better alternatives

Comment: @alex How would I reset counter to 1? I'm trying to find the simplest way to create an infinite loop which outputs consecutive integers by adding 1 each time to counter.

Comment: an integer can only hold so much data, I imagine you are getting the error due to to large of a number in counter. If you did something like if counter >30000 then counter = 1.... When you get the error what value is in counter and what line is the error on?

Answer (score 1):

For a loop that will run from 0..32767 repeatedly (the max an integer can hold)

```
Do While True
    counter = (counter + 1) Mod 32768
    ...
Loop
```

If you dim `counter` as a `Long` the maximum will be 2147483647.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just do this? and not increment counter at all?

```
Sub InfiniteLoop()
Dim counter As Integer
counter = 1
Do While counter > 0

Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: that works, it used 70% of my CPU before it stopped responding.